# Counting number of derangements with extra numbers without an index

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, problem-solving, derangements

Say I have a set of numbers 1 through N, E.g. {1,2,3,4,5,6}

I want to find the number of derangements, but for e.g the first 4 places {a,b,c,d} where there are of course the numbers 1 through 4 that will not be in its initial position, but there is an extra case of numbers here of 5 and 6  which can be put in any place. e.g in this problem a valid 'derangement' type of set could be {6,5,4,3} but so could a normal derangement such as {4,3,2,1}.

Im not sure how to start this since I cannot think of a way to include 5 and 6 but excluding the fact that its not a derangement set of size 5 and 6.

Comment: To be clear, do you wish to construct sequences of length $4$ using the digits $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6$ in which none of the digits $1, 2, 3, 4$ is a fixed point?

Comment: Look at how the formula for derangements is crafted in the first place via an inclusion-exclusion argument.  Do exactly the same thing here.  The inclusion-exclusion argument will be identical but the numbers will be slightly different for your specific scenario.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Yes this is correct but It would be nice to generalize it for any length sequence up to = length of the set (which would just be derangements)

Comment: @JMoravitz What exactly does the normal derangement formula include and exclude?

Comment: Counting the opposite, counting the number of arrangements such that at least one of the positions has the corresponding number in the position.  Let $A_i$ be the event that position $i$ has number $i$ in it.  "At least one position matches" would be $|A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3\cup \cdots \cup A_n|$ which expands by inclusion-exclusion as $|A_1|+|A_2|+\dots-|A_1\cap A_2|-\dots +|A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3|+\dots \pm|A_1\cap \dots\cap A_n|$, each term of which should be straightforward to find.

Comment: I would have thought this was something all students of combinatorics was taught, especially those who have been introduced to the word "derangements".  Yes, there are other techniques to counting derangements (*e.g. recurrence relations*), but this is perhaps the most elementary argument and it highlights a powerful technique which is applicable to many more problems and problemtypes... such as the question you ask here in your OP.